# Regex for input text box

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text box for user input where user can enter only comma separated numbers. Comma at the end of the string is also allowed

I am done with regex for that

```
var regex=/^[0-9\,]+$/;
```

How to apply higher bound limit on each comma separated number?

lets say, maximum number is 10 digit

following is valid

> 11,22,333,555555
>   and
>
> 11,23,

following is invalid

> 111111111111111111111111,4,4

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ranadheemachineni/LZf7H/6083/) here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following pattern:

```
var regex = /^[0-9]{1,10}(?:,[0-9]{1,10})*$/;
```

This says to match any number of 1 to 10 digits, followed by a comma and another 1-10 digit number, this quantity zero or more times.

## Demo

Comment: Replace `+` with `{1,10}` to limit each number to 10 digits.

Comment: Thank you. thats exactly i am looking for

Comment: Hey, in the above, if comma is given it is expecting another digit to be followed. can we avoid that. for example 111, should also be positive.

Comment: Yes, because I assume that `123,` is an invalid number.  Is this not the case?

Comment: now only 111 allowed 111, is not allowed. as commas allowed by design can i have numbers and any number of commas

Comment: yeah. but users generally enter as edge case

Comment: No, this is not a likely edge case.  I have answered your question.  If you have other matching and non matching examples, then update your question.